# Trigger GitLab pipeline only when there is a merge from a specific branch or triggered by a webhook

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a pipeline, and I want the master branch to be triggered only when staging branch gets merged into master, or when received a webhook. But I want to do it from workflow rules rather than `only` in each stage.

From there I will have specific rules in each stage depending if it is a trigger via webhook or via merge.

It is clear that the webhook trigger part is like this:

```
- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "trigger"
```

The way I was able to trigger the pipeline when the merge is done is like this:

```
- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
  when: never
- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
```

But this config also triggers when I push to master branch from the terminal, when I edit a file from the UI and when I merge from any branch. So not ideal. My final workflow section looks like this:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - changes:
      - .gitlab-ci.yml
      - Dockerfile
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
      when: never
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "trigger"
    - when: never
```

I just have that `changes` part to avoid waiting for the pipeline to end or to cancel it every time I make a test changing the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, but I also want to avoid triggering the pipeline when a file is edited from the UI, although in production that will never happen.

When I remove `- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` it just stops triggering upon the merge, which makes sense as there is no rule to trigger with a commit.

I only need this to be triggered with webhook, and a merge from staging.

Answer (score 0):

> master branch to be triggered only when staging branch gets merged
> into master

To achieve `master` branch build you can use below job rule:

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'master'
```

or better if your default branch is `master`:

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

Yes, it still has the issue that committing to `main` branch is possible.

Limiting the triggering to only when staging branch gets merged might be a bit tricky because `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME` is not available after merging merge request.

Workaround that comes to mind is extracting the MR src branch name using GitLab api and failing the pipeline if it's not `staging` branch. You'd need access token defined as project/group variable for that.

Below code shows how to get MR src branch from GitLab api:

```
variables:
  COMMIT_MERGE_REQ_URL: "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/repository/commits/$CI_COMMIT_SHA/merge_requests"
script:
  - merge_req=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $ACCESS_TOKEN" $COMMIT_MERGE_REQ_URL)
  - MR_BRANCH_NAME=$(echo $merge_req | jq -r '.[0].source_branch')
```